# Why isnt sorted(arr[1:]) not generating the desired list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, sorting

I encountered a question in coding where they give a list of integers and we have to print the maximum possible sum from the list by leaving one element alone.

So this is my code in Python:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    print(sorted(arr))
    print(sorted(arr[1:]))
    maxs=str(sum(sorted(arr[1:])))
    return maxs
print(miniMaxSum([7,69,2,221,8974]))
```

Now I cant understand why sorted(arr[1:]) is not giving [7,69,221,8974]?

Comment: You can add one more print statement `print(arr[1:])` to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `sum(sorted(arr[1:]))` you first slice, then sort. This makes your sorting step useless.

You need to **first sort, then slice**:

```
sum(sorted(arr)[1:])
```